# 24 Bit Toolbar Button Images? (WinAPI)

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I'm using pure win32. How can I use 24 bit images instead of 8 bit?

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps you should post your 8-bit code as an example so people know what they need to change?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the imagelist for the toolbar with the [TB_SETIMAGELIST](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb787433(VS.85).aspx) message.